# How to create and display user content submission form and display it in a block?

Tags: blocks

I want to build a user feedback form to create a content type which can be outputted as a view page. What I discover is that, i can create a new content type in which anonymous user can add contents, but I need that form to be in a block on a sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [form block module](https://drupal.org/project/formblock).

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for
>   including forms on panels.

Since the drupal 7 version is still in development, make sure to test it on a development site before moving it to a live site.